# How to add RxJS 5 as a bower dependency

Tags: bower, rxjs5

On the GitHub [page](https://github.com/Reactivex/RxJS#installation-and-usage), there are instructions only for NPM. When using 
`bower search rxjs`, I got only the RxJS 4.x results. Does it mean the RxJS 5.x hasn't been "bowerized" yet?

Is there a way to do the ${subject}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJS 5 has not been added to Bower, no. At this point NPM is recommended. This is primarily because Bower is just a fascade to GitHub and has a variety of other issues. We're also trying to follow the movement of more modern libraries moving away from Bower. There are also CDNs you can use.

If you strongly feel we should support bower [file an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues) so the whole community can discuss it. Thus far there hasn't been any demand though.

Comment: I'd argue in favor of Bower support because VS2017 and ASP.NET Core 2 really push you towards using Bower. Folks who use VS2017 with AspNetCore are likely going to run into this same issue. (I did, and searching for the solution is how I found this post.)

Comment: "At this point NPM is recommended" any suggestion on how to follow this path?